# Is it possible to code a "reply" to Facebook Messages in Notification Centre in Maverick OS X?

Tags: facebook, osx-mavericks

Is it possible to edit some code in Notification Center to allow Facebook messenger notifications to have a "Reply" or "Close" similar to iMessage?

Answer (score -1):

No. It's impossible for now. Maybe Apple